# BERT preprocessor to process .xlsx file

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, bert-language-model, keras-layer

I am doing a music artist classification using BERT in Tensor Flow. The goal is that given lyrics, the model should be able to identify the artist. My dataset is organized in a .xlsx file with three columns ('lyrics_title', 'lyrics', and 'artist') and 3479 rows.

When I pass the data frame, df, to the BERT preprocess model, I get the below error. How can I solve it? The code is provided as well, and any help will be appreciated.

```
#reading xlsx data into pandas dataframe
path_to_data = '/content/drive/MyDrive/AI/dataset_without_date.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_data)

#Getting BERT components from the url: preprocessor and encoder
preprocess_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'
encoder_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4'

#text preprocessing
bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(preprocess_url)
text_preprocessed = bert_preprocess_model(df)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b049c7e0f5b3> in <cell line: 3>()
  1 #text preprocessing
  2 bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(preprocess_url)
----> 3 text_preprocessed = bert_preprocess_model(df)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py in <lambda>()
242       result = smart_cond.smart_cond(training,
243                                      lambda: f(training=True),
--> 244                                      lambda: f(training=False))
245 
246     # Unwrap dicts returned by signatures.

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'keras_layer_1' (type KerasLayer).

Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

Call arguments received by layer 'keras_layer_1' (type KerasLayer):
```

• inputs=                   lyrics_title  
0                    god’s plan
1                in my feelings
2                 hotline bling
3                     one dance
4     hold on, we’re going home
...                         ...
3474                 weak heart
3475       what could have been
3476             wish them well
3477             you can profit
3478                 young tree

```
                                             lyrics       artist  
0     and they wishin' and wishin' and wishin' and w...        Drake  
1     drake trap trapmoneybenny this shit got me in ...        Drake  
2     you used to call me on my you used to you used...        Drake  
3     kyla baby i like your style   drake grips on y...        Drake  
4     produced by nineteen85 majid jordan  noah 40 s...        Drake  
...                                                 ...          ...  
3474  see the writing pon the wall to those who thin...  Groundation  
3475  what could have been the first moment in… my d...  Groundation  
3476  we want to be free but not only for we jah we ...  Groundation  
3477  you can be, anything you want to be all of you...  Groundation  
3478  dem trying to cut down dem young tree don't wa...  Groundation  

[3479 rows x 3 columns]
• training=None
```